# SQL server find previous sales based on previous draw for the same day

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms-2017, ssms-2016

> I have below dataset

[image]

> I'm looking for an SQL server query to get below output that will calculate previous sales based on previous draw number for the same day

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`LAG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to do this.

```
SELECT RETAILER_NUMBER, DRAW_NUM, DAY_NAME, ACTUAL_SALES,
       LAG(ACTUAL_SALES, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY RETAILER_NUMBER, DAY_NAME ORDER BY DRAW_NUM) AS PREVIOUS_SALES
FROM YOUR_TABLE
```